# My Machine Learning model doesn't work in Heroku but works perfectly on my local machine

Tags: python, machine-learning, flask, heroku

I have created an ML model for House price prediction using Flask. It is a Web Application. When I run it locally it works perfectly fine but after deploying it in Heroku the ML model doesn't work at all perhaps the web application runs perfectly.

Here is the link of my Web App: https://ml-housepriceprediction.herokuapp.com/

I have created a Flask server for my web app as well as ML model in a single file named as "app.py"

app.py

```
    from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
    from website import create_app
    import util
    import util_2
    import util_3

    app =  create_app()


    # bangalore
    @app.route('/get_location_names', methods=['GET'])
    def get_location_names():
        response = jsonify({
            'locations': util.get_location_names()
        })
        response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')

        return response

    @app.route('/predict_home_price', methods=['POST'])
    def predict_home_price():
        total_sqft = float(request.form['total_sqft'])
        location = request.form['location']
        bhk = int(request.form['bhk'])
        bath = int(request.form['bath'])

        response = jsonify({
            'estimated_price': util.get_estimated_price(location, total_sqft, bhk, bath)
        })

        response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')

        return response

    #mumbai
    @app.route('/get_location_names_m', methods=['GET'])
    def get_location_names_m():
        response = jsonify({
            'locations': util_2.get_location_names()
        })
        response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')

        return response

    @app.route('/predict_home_price_m', methods=['POST'])
    def predict_home_price_m():
        total_sqft = float(request.form['total_sqft'])
        location = request.form['location']
        bhk = int(request.form['bhk'])
        bath = int(request.form['bath'])

        response = jsonify({
            'estimated_price': util_2.get_estimated_price(location, total_sqft, bhk, bath)
        })

        response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')

        return response

    #delhi
    @app.route('/get_location_names_d', methods=['GET'])
    def get_location_names_d():
        response = jsonify({
            'locations': util_3.get_location_names()
        })
        response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')

        return response

    @app.route('/predict_home_price_d', methods=['POST'])
    def predict_home_price_d():
        total_sqft = float(request.form['total_sqft'])
        location = request.form['location']
        bhk = int(request.form['bhk'])
        bath = int(request.form['bath'])

        response = jsonify({
            'estimated_price': util_3.get_estimated_price(location, total_sqft, bhk, bath)
        })

        response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')

        return response

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        print("Starting Python Flask Server For Home Price Prediction...")
        util.load_saved_artifacts()
        util_2.load_saved_artifacts()
        util_3.load_saved_artifacts()
        app.run()
```

Procfile

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

requirements.txt

```
    asgiref==3.3.1
    astroid==2.5
    autopep8==1.5.6
    beautifulsoup4==4.9.3
    bs4==0.0.1
    certifi==2020.12.5
    chardet==4.0.0
    click==7.1.2
    colorama==0.4.4
    Django==3.0.4
    Flask==1.0.2
    Flask-Login==0.5.0
    Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
    greenlet==1.0.0
    gunicorn==20.1.0
    html5lib==1.1
    idna==2.10
    isort==5.7.0
    itsdangerous==1.1.0
    Jinja2==2.11.3
    joblib==1.0.1
    lazy-object-proxy==1.5.2
    MarkupSafe==1.1.1
    mccabe==0.6.1
    MouseInfo==0.1.3
    numpy==1.20.1
    Pillow==8.2.0
    PyAutoGUI==0.9.52
    pycodestyle==2.7.0
    PyGetWindow==0.0.9
    pylint==2.7.0
    PyMsgBox==1.0.9
    pyperclip==1.8.2
    PyRect==0.1.4
    PyScreeze==0.1.27
    PyTweening==1.0.3
    pytz==2021.1
    pywhatkit==4.7
    requests==2.25.1
    scikit-learn==0.24.2
    scipy==1.6.2
    six==1.15.0
    sklearn==0.0
    soupsieve==2.2.1
    SQLAlchemy==1.4.12
    sqlparse==0.4.1
    threadpoolctl==2.1.0
    toml==0.10.2
    urllib3==1.26.4
    webencodings==0.5.1
    Werkzeug==1.0.1
    wikipedia==1.4.0
    wrapt==1.12.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your app.py has 5 imports but your requirements.txt has much more packages.

If you use pip freeze > requirements.txt. without be in a virtual environment, the pip freeze will write all packages from your local python.exe to your requirements.txt

Also, Heroku is a headless server, which means that computers have not monitors or whatever peripherals and you can't deploy pyautogui or mouseinfo, packages that requires a mouse and a monitor to localize the cursor on the screen. And that libraries are written in your requirements.txt